# Rename the atom tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

The [atom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/atom) tag is currently being used for questions about GitHub's Atom editor and Intel's Atom CPU. I would favour a new tag for either.

Maybe the best practice is to follow Stack Overflow and create [atom-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/atom-editor) for the former tag.

Comment: There are only 74 questions with this tag. Easy to retag :)